# Trying to convert a code from Python2.7 to Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a piece of code which captures the service tag of a machine.
Below is the code:

```
import os,sys,time
import os.path
import subprocess
import string

test_cmd='wmic bios get serialnumber /value'

output = subprocess.check_output(test_cmd)

start=output.rfind("SerialNumber=")+13

output=output[start:]

servicetag=output

print ("Service Tag = %s" %servicetag) #get the service tag
```

The code seems to work in Python2.7 but I couldn't get it to work in Python3.5.
The error message show as below, and I couldn't make anything out of it.

```
start=output.rfind("SerialNumber=")+13

TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'"
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`output = subprocess.check_output(test_cmd)`

With Python 2, `output` would have been of type `str`, with Python 3 it will be of type `bytes`.

The simplest solution would be to convert the output from `check_output` from `bytes` to `str` .

Comment: Convert is probably the wrong word since it implies using `str(output)` which is incorrect. The output must be *decoded*. I.e: `output = subprocess.check_output(test_cmd).decode()`.